# Invoke EXE from batch file *without* waiting

Tags: batch-file

How do I invoke an EXE from a batch file without having the latter waiting for the EXE to finish? Something like the Cygwin 'cygstart'?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use "`start`".  Type "`start /?`" at a command prompt.

Comment: Careful, though, if your command contains spaces. In that case you have to use `start "" "command with spaces.exe"`

Comment: I see "When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application, CMD.EXE does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to the command prompt.  **This new behavior does NOT occur if executing within a command script.**" in the output of "start /? on Windows 7" But how make this behaviour if I need?..

Answer (score 7):

put START /B before the command you want to run

Comment: That's the right and better way for me instead of START without /B. The reasons are: * The process act directly to my current cmd, thats important e.g. if want modify somewhat with powershell; * Less system resources are needed because no additional process is opened.

Answer (score 4):

Just `start foo.exe`? You need to add `/WAIT` to make it pause.

Comment: you need `start "sometitle" foo.exe`, or simply `start "" foo.exe`