# Thunderbird compose email in a batch script - continue to next command

Tags: batch-file, thunderbird

Using the following line in a batch script to call thunderbird and compose an email:

```
thunderbird.exe -compose "to='email@domain.com',subject='Some Subject',preselectid='id1',body='Message Body',attachment='File.txt'"
```

The command performs perfectly fine, however the batch script will not continue until the application terminates.  Is there a way to bypass this so that the script will continue on with the next command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke EXE from batch file *without* waiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648172/invoke-exe-from-batch-file-without-waiting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `start /b` before the command, and the batch script will continue to execute after launching the process.

Comment: Off-note: Is there a difference between running a program directly (e.g. CMD C:\Some\Program.exe) or with the START command with a /WAIT switch?

Comment: Doesn't the /b switch hide the application? "Start application without creating a new window"(via cmd  START /?)

Comment: Good question, don't know the difference. `start` opens a console window which is  not what you want, hence the `/b` flag

Comment: START /B works well for this.  Just a note however, if you are referencing the absolute path (e.g. C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe -compose "to='email@domain.com',subject='Some Subject',preselectid='id1',body='Message Body',attachment='File.txt'") It will fail because a path with spaces requires quotations, but the Thunderbird command line arguments requires quotations as well so you receive an error.

Thanks Charles

Comment: @Mechaflash to avoid this you can CD into `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird` before calling start, now without absolute path (nor quotes) since `thunderbird.exe` is in this directory

Comment: i believe thunderbird.exe is registered globally (at least in WindowsXP) so you can call the exe from anywhere.

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't have it installed so I can't say. However most programs don't register themselves in the `PATH` environment variable, so you have to CD into the correct directory

Comment: I dunno hows I dun it but I knows I dun it  XD

Comment: is it possible to have the script actually send the email?