# How to open a video in wmp with .bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, windows-media-player, wmplayer

WMP = windows media player.
So yea I want to use .bat to open 2 different videos same time but in two different media players, because... well one does not do the job, opens the video 1 and replaces with the other video. So I have a W10 app as default to watch videos but it can only play one video, not two the same time. So I thought of using wmplayer.exe to open the other video, but I just don't have any idea how to do it. So what I have already done is
start video1.mp4
start video2.mp4    but I want to use wmplayer to open this video, how is that possible?

Comment: A quick google search I found this. It looks like it may help. http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-windows-media-player/ Follow those steps and try running your batch again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this topic, can be helpfull:

[Invoke EXE from batch file *without* waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648172/invoke-exe-from-batch-file-without-waiting)

start "yourexe.exe" /b open software without waiting.