# starting weblogic waits for hitting enter and gets stuck

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

This is happening in my windows 7 installation, I start weblogic by running 
startWeblogic.cmd

in 3 different stages of starting  the application servver, the command line waits for hit enter , which is problematic because I would like to  start the applciation withouth interaction, anyone has happened through this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end was the way the command file is executed, It works fine when I use the command start
I've found the answer here :
[Invoke EXE from batch file *without* waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648172/invoke-exe-from-batch-file-without-waiting)